# How to get the particular field from the couchdb views result using couchdb list function

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb

Below i mentioned the design document.

```
       {
        "_id": "_design/link",
        "_rev": "62-0c0f00dd9dbedab5c2cca61c356bbff4",
        "views": {
         "link": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n if (doc.projects) { for (var i in    doc.projects) { emit(doc._id, {_id: doc.projects[i].proj_id}); }} \n}"
},
          "lists": {
          "sample": "function(head, req) {while(row = getRow()){  send(row.doc.proj_name);} }"
}
}
```

}

The view result:

```
{
total_rows: 1,
offset: 0,
rows: [
{
 id: "SCI130202",
 key: "SCI130202",
 value: {
       _id: "PID00034"
        },
 doc: {
     _id: "PID00034",
     _rev: "1-0a363e98a605a72fd71bb4ac62e0b138",
     client_id: "E000022",
     client_name: "Edinburgh Steel",
     type: "manage projects",
     proj_id: "PID00034",
     proj_name: "Global_upgrade_Oracle",
     proj_domain: "Information Technology",
     proj_start_date: "2014-10-08",
     proj_end_date: "2015-07-07",
     delivery_manager: null,
     proj_standards: null,
     proj_currency_type: "INR",
     onsite: "No",
     location: "Edinburgh",
     proj_status: "Noy yet Start",
     budgeted_margin: 45,
     budgeted_hrs: 300,
     projected_revenue: 200000,
     billing_rate: 30,
     unit_measure: "per month",
     billing_cycle: "Milestone",
     proj_core_tech_skills: [ ],
     proj_secon_skills: [ ],
     proj_sdlc_skills: [ ],
     tag: "",
     margin: [
              {
                desired_onsite: null,
                desired_offshore: null,
                lower_limit: null
              }
            ]
      }
   }
]
```

}

I tried but the error comes like

**function raised error: (new TypeError("row.doc is undefined", ""))**
How to get the proj_name,proj_start_date and proj_end_date using couchdb list function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `include_docs=true` option to the URL you are using to query the view/list. Views do **not** automatically include the document.

Answer (score 0):

And maybe you shouldn't use a list to filter your view result - just let the view emit what you need:

```
emit(doc._id, {
  _id: doc.projects[i].proj_id
});
```

Turns into:

```
emit(doc.proj_id, {
  proj_name: doc.proj_name,
  proj_id: doc.proj_id,
  proj_start_date: doc.proj_start_date,
  proj_end_date: doc.proj_end_date
});
```

You don't need to emit the `doc._id` - it is automatically emitted for every row.